# How to output process id in vbs / why is this not working

Tags: vbscript, pid

I am  an absolute noob in vbs but so far, i have modified a script, which scans all the running processes and if they fall under the 'application'  then it's name is outputted to a csv file.

```
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Dim fso
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set f = fso.CreateTextFile("output.csv", 2)
Set Tasks = Word.Tasks
For Each obj in Tasks
   PID = obj.ProcessID
   If obj.Visible Then f.Writeline obj.Name & "," & PID
Next
Word.Quit
```

My aim is to, get a list of all application, and after reading the name decide which to terminate and kill it using it's process id (which you get from the csv file).

It is able to correctly output the name however if i try to output processID i keep getting this:

> Object doesn't support this property or method:
>    'obj.ProcessID'
>     Code : 800A02B6

There is not much help online, most examples i see use x.processID  to find processID.

Can someone tell me why it does not work in the above code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, read the documentation. [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845120.aspx) objects don't have a property `ProcessID`. Better use [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372.aspx) for enumerating processes:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
For Each p In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")
  WScript.Echo p.ProcessId
Next
```

Comment: This method only shows the process id, i need the application name and it's process id.

Comment: @vulcanicrook If you'd taken an actual look at the documentation I linked to you might have noticed that the `Win32_Process` class also provides a property `Name`. Consider adding this property to my sample code your homework.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i didn't explain properly, I meant, I need to filter and only have processes which are 'applications' or the processes in the application tab in task manager. From what i understand, the code which uses tasks, use ms word as a object and sees any other objects like it are visible and outputs it name. I am unsure how to do this with wmi

Comment: The `Tasks` collection contains a lot more than just what is show in the "Application" view of the Task Manager. You're better off using `Win32_Process`.